# Setup Project versus Bootstrapper Project for checking and installing prerequisites

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

Here is my situation:

- I create a normal WiX Setup project.
- Then I try to check some prerequisites like if the .NET framework is installed or not.
- It seems that I am not able to do this from a WiX Setup project. So I create
  WiX Bootstrapper project and am able to check for and install those
  prerequisites.
- I try to use the WiX Bootstrapper in the WiX Setup project but can not. The examples I see was, the WiX Bootstrapper project uses the Setup project with the `MsiPackage` tag.

It seems strange to me to start setup project from Bootstrapper project. Instead I prefer to start prerequisites check and installation from Setup project (maybe calling out to the bootstrapper project from the setup project).

So here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to check for and install some prerequisites the .NET framework in Wix Setup project? If so, how?
2. Is it okay to start the application from the WiX Bootstrapper *and* call the WiX setup project from it? Is that the general convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is possible to check for Dotnet from the wix setup. But you cannot install pre requisites from the setup. So you can pop a message asking to install dotnet before installing.

This is how to check for dotnet 4.0 using wix.

```
<Property Id="DOTNET40">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework40"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4"
             Name="Install"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>


<Condition Message="Please install the .NET Framework 4.0 and run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR DOTNET40]]>
</Condition>
```

2. Checking for pre requisites and installing them using the bootstrapper is the general convention. The main reason to use a bootstrapper is to install the pre requisites and then install your setup.