# create one click setup containing more than 1 exe/msi files

Tags: c#

My desktop application is in Visual Studio 2008 and
i want to create a set up(.exe) file which contain more than 1 exe/utility/msi files
for example such as 
Project Setup.exe, 
Window Installer 3.1, 
.Net Framwork 3.5,
Crystal Report Basic For Visual Studio 2008,
Mysql Server 5.0

In other hand, want to create one click setup containing more than 1 exe/msi files.
suggest any idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs and toolsets that can be used for created a one-click installer. One such toolset is [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).
For a simple C# application all you need to do is [Link](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)
As an example on how to check for prerequistes. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717910/3868791)

Another one I've used before is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)